# submit input field using enter key

Tags: javascript, node.js, input, form-submit

I'm building the weather app and want to submit the city name to the server using the Enter key.
I am getting the error

> submit is not a funtion

I want to fix this and i want to know how can i send the value to the express server in order to use it in API calls.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Weather APP</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input id="City" placeholder="EnterCity" onclick="u()" action="/" method="post">
</body>
<script>
    function u(){
            document.getElementById("City").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        var x = document.getElementById("City");
        x.submit();
        return false;
    }
});
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `input` inside a form tag, and submitting the form instead of the input tag

```
...
<body>
    <form id="CityForm" onsubmit="u()" action="/" method="post">
        <input id="City" placeholder="EnterCity" />
    </form>
</body>
<script>
    function u(){
            document.getElementById("City").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        var x = document.getElementById("CityForm");
        x.submit();
        return false;
    }
});
}
</script>
...
```

You submit form's, not individual input elements. On your input element you can have an action like `onChange` which will run every time the input tag get's input, but the actual submission is handled by the form