# How to send a GET request on "keydown" in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, keydown, spotify-app

I've been working with Spotify api on my music app project (nothing too complex). Now I've ran into a problem which I've tried solving to no avail. Allowing users to send GET request to the backend simply by pressing Enter key on their keyboard. It works while the input search icon is clicked but not when the Enter key is pressed. All I get is 400 error anytime I tried sending the GET request by hitting the Enter key.

```
 async function getArtists() {
      try {
         setIsFetching(true);
         const response = await fetch(
            `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + ${input} + "&type=artist`,
            artistParameter
         );
         if (response.status === 200) {
            setIsFetching(false);
            const data = await response.json();
            const { items } = data.artists;
            setIsSearchedArtists(items);
            setIsSearchTrue(true);
         }
      } catch (e) {
         console.log(e.message);
      }
   }
```

```
 function enterKeyPressHandler(e) {
      if (e.key === "Enter") {
         e.preventDefault();
         getArtists();
      }
   }
```

Checking if the key been pressed is the 'Enter' key, if yes call the the getArtists function which shoud send the GET request to the server but for some reasons it's just not working.

```
 useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener("keydown", enterKeyPressHandler);
      return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", enterKeyPressHandler);
   }, []);
```

Just notice that whenever I send the request by hitting the "Enter" key , this is how it's been sent `Request URL: https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=&type=artist` 
omitting the `input` state which is supposed to be the value of the input tag. Compared to how it's been sent when I click the search icon `Request URL: https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Drake&type=artist`.

Finally found the answer here [submit input field using enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838105/submit-input-field-using-enter-key)

Comment: Have you any `form` and `button` tags on your page, Enter key is the default key for form submit.

Comment: just an `input` tag @Keith

Comment: It's not really what I asked, `any` other `form` or `button` tags on your page.  Are you saying there is only a single `input` tag on this page with no others buttons etc.  If so, you might need to knock up a simple snippet, as I see no reason why a fetch won't work from a keypress rather than a button click.

Comment: Can you paste the error message and the url you send get? You said it returns 400,

Comment: There's no other `form` or `button` just an `input` tag. it's a search input which should fire off on keydown

Comment: This the error '**GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=%22%20+%20%20+%20%22&type=artist 400
getArtists
enterKeyPressHandler** ' @AvetikNersisyan

Comment: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${input}&type=artist`  You are using template literals wrong, but that doesn't explain why the button way works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where your ${input} inserted into the url is getting its value from. Assuming this is from the closure around the function, what could be happening is that the getArtists function is holding onto an out of date value for input from the closure when the function was created.

React relies on functions like this being regenerated on every render cycle, which means their closures get updated to the values on the cycle. However it looks like in the useEffect you are attaching a specific version of the function to the event handler, which can then become outdated on later render cycles. Since the useEffect runs on every render cycle, it looks like it should throw away the old version in the cleanup function and attach an new one. This might not be working though depending on what order these things are done in the actual component.

Hope this gives you a pointer.

Comment: I think you might be right cause I modified the "enterKeyPressHandler" function by having it return the "getArtists" function.  It's actually firing now but not just updating my input value which I store in a input state.  @James Ellis-Jones